# Use inferno-devtools in a chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, infernojs

I'm working on a chrome extension popup that uses inferno.  So far, my inferno components themselves are rendering just fine in the popup, so inferno itself is working.

I installed `inferno-devtools` in my dependencies.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Workflow",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Workflow",
    "default_popup": "/index.html"
  },
  "permissions":["tabs", "storage", "*://example.com/*" ]
}
```

`index.html` has `<div id="root"></div>` in the body and a `<script>` tag that loads the js.

In my main js file I have the following:

```
import Inferno from 'inferno'
... // other imports
require('inferno-devtools')

// redux store code

Inferno.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <WorkflowApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

`<WorkflowApp />` can be any connected inferno functional component (via inferno-redux's `connect` method).  This is all rendering fine in the popup and is arbitrary, so I'm omitting it here.

**The problem: in Chrome devtools I do not see the React tab showing up.**  I have a separate React-based application that I use the React devtools on where it shows up just fine, so it's installed and working well.

Is there something specific I need to do to get it to work with inferno in a Chrome extension?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen - I've added code to make the question more complete.  Let me know if there's anything specific still needed.

Answer (score 0):

You got to just run imported init function like this: `require('inferno-devtools').initDevTools()` or

```js
import { initDevTools } from 'inferno-devtools';
initDevTools();
```